# how to save my cart in cookies and update it in cookies

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have AngularJS shopping cart. I'm trying to save all my cart in cookies and I have a problem. When I refresh my page, my old cart is removed. I want to update quantity if product is already in cart or, if is not in cart, I want to put it in cookies. Here is my code:

```js
 $scope.cart = [];
            $scope.cartList = [];
            $scope.addToCart = function (car, quantity) {
                if (car.toCartQty > car.quantity) {
                    alert("The quantity is not available");
                    return false;
                }
                var isInCart = false;
                var myIndex = -1;
              
                if (!$cookieStore.get('cook')) {
                    $cookieStore.put('cook', $scope.cart)

                }
                
                _.find($scope.cart, function (val, i) {
                    console.log($scope.cart[i]);
                    if ($scope.cart[i].id == car.id) {
                        myIndex = i;
                        isInCart = true;

                    }
                })


                console.log('index', myIndex, isInCart);
                if (isInCart == true) {
                    car.quantity = car.quantity - car.toCartQty;
                    $scope.cart[myIndex].qty = $scope.cart[myIndex].qty + parseInt(car.toCartQty);
                } else {
                    car.qty = parseInt(car.toCartQty);
                    car.quantity = car.quantity - car.toCartQty;
                    $scope.cart.push(car);

                }
                
                car.toCartQty = 0;
                $cookieStore.put('cook', $scope.cart);

            };
            

            $scope.readCookie = function () {

                $scope.cartNew = $cookieStore.get('cook');
                console.log($scope.cartNew)
            };
            $scope.removeCart = function () {
                $cookieStore.remove('cook');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularjs-locker:

add locker to your project and inject it in your controller:

```
yourController.$inject = ['locker'];
function yourController('locker')
{
    //when you want save a data
    locker.put('nameOfVariable', value);
    //when you get data
    locker.get('nameOfVariable');
    //To create or recover your variable (cart)
    if(locker.get('cartList') == null)
    {
        $scope.cartList = [];
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.cartList = locker.get('cartList');
    }
}
```

I had the same problem and I resolve it with locker.